# Using 2 byte arrays in C# Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to write a `[DataTestMethod]` that uses many `[DataRow]`s, all containing two byte arrays.
But, my problem is that the test method only uses the Data from the last row.

I have written a Test with data rows that just contains integers which works fine. And another one that containes one Byte array and some bools. But I can't get a multiple data rows with two byte arrays to work.

Working Tests:

```
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow(1, 1, 2)]
    [DataRow(2, 2, 4)]
    [DataRow(3, 3, 6)]
    public void AddTests(int x, int y, int expected)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, x + y);
    }

    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00 }, false, false, false)]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00 }, true, true, false)]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00 }, false, true, false)]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00 }, true, false, false)]
    [DataTestMethod()]
    public void ByteArrayIntegerTest(byte[] key,bool ctorsign, bool tasign,bool expectfail)
    {
        var bi = new ByteArrayInteger(key, ctorsign);
        var result = bi.ToByteArray(tasign);
        if (expectfail)
        {
            CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(key, result);
        }
        else
        {
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(key, result);
        }
    }
```

Not working Test:

```
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE }, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE })]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00, 0xCA, 0xFE }, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE })]
    [DataRow(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xCA, 0xFE }, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE })]

    public void MinimizeSerialnumberTest(byte[] serialnumber, byte[] expected)
    {
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, Util.MinimizeSerialnumber(serialnumber));
    }
```

With the non working test it only ever uses the last provided `DataRow`. There are no errors and the test runs just fine.

Does `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` not support multiple byte arrays? Or what could be the problem?

Edit:
After some more research. Could the Problem be, that `DataRowAttribute` takes `Object, Object[]` as parameters in it's constructor? [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)

If so, how would I work with that?

Comment: In the test explorer, does it show the test was run 3 times, with the inputs used for each test?  Or does it show the test was only run once

Comment: For the non-working test it shows it only once. For the other two working tests it shows all the test results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was the constructor of `DataRowAttribute`. I changed my data rows to the following and now everything works as intended.

```
[DataRow(1, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE }, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE })]
[DataRow(2, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xCA, 0xFE }, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE })]
```

Comment: Strange. Did you also add a (dummy) int parameter to your test?

Comment: Do you mean the test method? 
Yes it's now like this:
MinimizeSerialnumberTests(int testno, byte[] serialnumber, byte[] expected)

Answer (score 2):

> Edit:
> After some more research. Could the Problem be, that `DataRowAttribute` takes `Object, Object[]` as parameters in it's constructor?

Yes, that seems to be the case. The second parameter is `params`, so the compiler performs the following translations:

```
           first argument --+    +--- array of remaining arguments
                            |    |
                            v    v
DataRow(1, 2, 3) -> DataRow(1, new object[] { 2, 3 });
DataRow(1, 2)    -> DataRow(1, new object[] { 2 });
```

However, the compiler *won't* translate `DataRow(1, someObjectArray)` to `DataRow(1, new object[] { someObjectArray })`, but rather keep the object array as it is. This is necessary in case you want to actually pass an object array containing all (remaining) parameters for your test method.

Since `byte[]` is implicitly convertible to `object[]` (an unfortunate legacy left-over from the old days when we didn't have generics), it appears that

- your `byte[]` is implicitly converted to an `object[]` and then
- this `object[]` is used as the second parameter,

resulting in the following data row for your test: `{ 0xCA, 0xFE }, 0xCA, 0xFE` (rather than the indented `{ 0xCA, 0xFE }, { 0xCA, 0xFE }`).

> If so, how would I work with that?

Explicitly wrap your second parameter in an object[]:

```
[DataRow(new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE }, new object[] { new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE } })]
```

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. However, even if I explicitly wrap my parameter, it still only uses the last DataRow I provide. If I use the code I provided in my answer it uses all the DataRows. And right now I can't understand why.